# How do i use an iterator to go though a Vector and find certain Objects?

Tags: java, vector, nullpointerexception, iterator

My issue is that I need to find the objects in the Vector contents so that i can print  them to a panel. However when i use this code to iterate through the vector it doesn't get to the object = it.next() lines. And so it gives me a null pointer when i try to call the objects paint method as the object is not initialized.

```
 public PaintingPanel(Vector contents){
    this.contents = contents;
    Iterator it = contents.iterator();

    while(it.hasNext()){
        if(it.next().equals(ball)){
            ball = (Ball) it.next(); 
        } else if (it.next().equals(bricks)){
            bricks.add((Brick) it.next());
        } else if (it.next().equals(paddle)){
            paddle = (Paddle) it.next();
        }
```

Comment: Answerers, please say something about `vector` and *raw*..

Comment: the pattern is strange, why would you need the assignement if equals

Answer (score 5):

An `Iterator` will advance one value *each time* you call `.next()`. In your loop, you advance three times, therefore swallow three entries!

Do this instead:

```
Object element;
while (it.hasNext()) {
    element = it.next();
    if (element.equals(ball)) // etc etc
}
```

---

Also, you should not use a `Vector`. Not in 2014.

Use a `List<X>` where `X` is the correct type instead!

---

Finally, you seem to have other problems given that your question states "it doesn't get to the object = it.next() lines". More code is needed! And given the strangeness of your `if` predicates, the problem looks to be more fundamental than that, even.

In particular, you hit a `NullPointerException` "instead of" a `NoSuchElementException` which is what an `Iterator` throws if it does not have any more elements to produce.

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating over with each if/else condition. Better store the retrieved object and then do the comparisons. Maybe something like this:

```
       while(it.hasNext()){
        Object itObj = it.next();
        if(itObj.equals(ball)){
            ball = (Ball) it.next(); 
        } else if ((itObj.equals(bricks)){
            bricks.add((Brick) it.next());
        } else if ((itObj.equals(paddle)){
            paddle = (Paddle) it.next();
        }
```